# Can a nested SQL subquery be accessed by other subqueries in the same Select statement..?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

This is for an IBM AS400 DB2 SQL server vr61m0, accessed via the DBeaver SQL client. I have what is for me the most complicated query I've yet created by manually writing any SQL, and parts of it have a duplication problem. Specifically, there's a subquery that gets used multiple times in different ways, and I'm hoping to mitigate that duplication so it only appears once.

I'm not sure what terminology to use for this, so it's been difficult to search on Google. I've tried bits like "subquery", "derived table", etc, but no luck. I get too many unrelated search results. It seems obvious to me this problem is an issue of scope: the various subquery environments cannot see each other.

To the point... If an SQL query has subqueries in the FROM clause, and one of them is used multiple times, but in some cases it's nested into deeper subqueries for application of aggregate functions, can the deeper subqueries refer to the shallower one to avoid duplication..??

Here's a working example that I've created, with working data. This is a very condensed example that's based on the real query & data that I'm working with. The duplicated subqueries are noted in the SQL with comments:

Data table `ORDERS`:

```
ORDDATE  ORDNUM ORDACCT  ORDLOAD 
20180901 1      ABC99    101     
20180901 2      XYZ00    102     
20180901 3      ZZZ12    103
```

Data table `LOADS`:

```
LOADDATE LOADNUM LOADDRIV LOADHLP1 LOADHLP2 RATEDRIV RATEHLP1 RATEHLP2 
20180901 101     57                         1                          
20180901 102     60       71                1        2                 
20180901 103     58       81       85       1        3        3
```

This SQL works, but the noted subquery is duplicated twice:

```
SELECT ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDACCT, ORDLOAD, TYPECODE AS LOADTYPE, EMPID, RATE

FROM        CERTODB.ORDERS AS ORDERS

                                      -- THE SUBQUERY BELOW IS THE FIRST DUPLICATION
INNER JOIN  (                         SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 1 AS LOADROLE, LOADDRIV AS EMPID, RATEDRIV AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE LOADDRIV>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 2 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP1 AS EMPID, RATEHLP1 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP1>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 3 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP2 AS EMPID, RATEHLP2 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP2>0
            ) AS LOADEMPS   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADEMPS.LOADDATE
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADEMPS.LOADNUM
INNER JOIN  (   SELECT      LOADDATE, LOADNUM, COUNT(LOADROLE) AS TYPECODE
                                      -- THE SUBQUERY BELOW IS THE SECOND DUPLICATION
                FROM        (         SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 1 AS LOADROLE, LOADDRIV AS EMPID, RATEDRIV AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE LOADDRIV>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 2 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP1 AS EMPID, RATEHLP1 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP1>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 3 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP2 AS EMPID, RATEHLP2 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP2>0
                            ) AS LOADEMPS
                GROUP BY    LOADDATE, LOADNUM
            ) AS LOADTYPE   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADTYPE.LOADDATE 
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADTYPE.LOADNUM

ORDER BY ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDLOAD, LOADROLE
```

Here an attempt is made to refer to the first subquery later in the main query, but it doesn't work. It produces the error: "SQL Error [42704]: [SQL0204] LOADEMPS in CERTODB type *FILE not found." As stated above, it seems to be an issue of scope: the subquery environments can't see each other.

Is there a way to make this work, or something like it, all within a single SQL query, so the duplication isn't there..? For instance, no extra views, stored procedures, or other objects, but all done in one big SQL statement..?

```
SELECT ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDACCT, ORDLOAD, TYPECODE AS LOADTYPE, EMPID, RATE

FROM        CERTODB.ORDERS AS ORDERS

INNER JOIN  (                         SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 1 AS LOADROLE, LOADDRIV AS EMPID, RATEDRIV AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE LOADDRIV>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 2 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP1 AS EMPID, RATEHLP1 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP1>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 3 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP2 AS EMPID, RATEHLP2 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP2>0
            ) AS LOADEMPS   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADEMPS.LOADDATE
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADEMPS.LOADNUM
INNER JOIN  (   SELECT      LOADDATE, LOADNUM, COUNT(LOADROLE) AS TYPECODE
                -- BELOW AN ATTEMPT IS MADE TO ACCESS THE PREVIOUS CALL OF THE SUBQUERY 'LOADEMPS', THUS REMOVING THE DUPLICATE
                FROM        LOADEMPS 
                GROUP BY    LOADDATE, LOADNUM
            ) AS LOADTYPE   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADTYPE.LOADDATE 
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADTYPE.LOADNUM

ORDER BY ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDLOAD, LOADROLE
```

Comment: Never re-use table aliases, just too confusing. Perhaps you're looking for a cte (common table expression), i.e. a `WITH` clause.

Comment: I use DB2 9.5 and 10.5 all the time and they have Common Table Expressions (CTEs). They allow you to "pre-compute" one or more queries and then use it/them in the next ones in the same `SELECT` statement. They are far simpler to write and debug that what you are trying to write.

Comment: Use CTE to solve this

Comment: Bingo..!! That's it exactly. Thank you to all, I've just stitched that into my SQL and it's already working. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/sqlp/rbafytabexp.htm

Comment: Also, a point which is omitted from the IBM link above, but is mentioned here... https://modern-sql.com/feature/with ..., a `WITH` clause can contain multiple CTEs, separated by commas. So I've moved *all* the subqueries (there were more) from the `FROM` clause to the `WITH` clause. It's all working, and the `FROM` clause is so much more readable now. <3

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `LATERAL` keyword would help

```
SELECT ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDACCT, ORDLOAD, TYPECODE AS LOADTYPE, EMPID, RATE

FROM        CERTODB.ORDERS AS ORDERS

INNER JOIN  (                         SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 1 AS LOADROLE, LOADDRIV AS EMPID, RATEDRIV AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE LOADDRIV>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 2 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP1 AS EMPID, RATEHLP1 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP1>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 3 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP2 AS EMPID, RATEHLP2 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP2>0
            ) AS LOADEMPS   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADEMPS.LOADDATE
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADEMPS.LOADNUM
INNER JOIN  LATERAL (   SELECT      LOADDATE, LOADNUM, COUNT(LOADROLE) AS TYPECODE
                -- BELOW AN ATTEMPT IS MADE TO ACCESS THE PREVIOUS CALL OF THE SUBQUERY 'LOADEMPS', THUS REMOVING THE DUPLICATE
                FROM        LOADEMPS 
                GROUP BY    LOADDATE, LOADNUM
            ) AS LOADTYPE   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADTYPE.LOADDATE 
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADTYPE.LOADNUM

ORDER BY ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDLOAD, LOADROLE
```

But as mentioned in the comments, I'd use a couple CTEs

```
with loademps as (SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 1 AS LOADROLE, LOADDRIV AS EMPID, RATEDRIV AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE LOADDRIV>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 2 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP1 AS EMPID, RATEHLP1 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP1>0
                                UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 3 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP2 AS EMPID, RATEHLP2 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP2>0
            )
, loadtypes as (   SELECT      LOADDATE, LOADNUM, COUNT(LOADROLE) AS TYPECODE
                -- BELOW AN ATTEMPT IS MADE TO ACCESS THE PREVIOUS CALL OF THE SUBQUERY 'LOADEMPS', THUS REMOVING THE DUPLICATE
                FROM        LOADEMPS 
                GROUP BY    LOADDATE, LOADNUM
            )
SELECT ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDACCT, ORDLOAD, TYPECODE AS LOADTYPE, EMPID, RATE
FROM        CERTODB.ORDERS AS ORDERS
INNER JOIN  LOADEMPS   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADEMPS.LOADDATE
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADEMPS.LOADNUM
INNER JOIN  LOADTYPE   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADTYPE.LOADDATE 
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADTYPE.LOADNUM
ORDER BY ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDLOAD, LOADROLE
```

Comment: Yes, I was just posting a followup comment in response to the others on my OP about that before your answer popped up. I've already moved all the subqueries from the `FROM` clause to the `WITH` clause. It's all working, more compact, and so much more eye-friendly now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in response to my OP, it seems I needed a Common Table Expression (CTE), aka WITH clause: https://modern-sql.com/feature/with

Below is the redesigned SQL, with the desired removal of duplication:

```
WITH LOADEMPS AS    (         SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 1 AS LOADROLE, LOADDRIV AS EMPID, RATEDRIV AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE LOADDRIV>0
                        UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 2 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP1 AS EMPID, RATEHLP1 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP1>0
                        UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 3 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP2 AS EMPID, RATEHLP2 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP2>0
                    )

SELECT ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDACCT, ORDLOAD, TYPECODE AS LOADTYPE, EMPID, RATE

FROM        CERTODB.ORDERS  AS ORDERS
INNER JOIN  LOADEMPS        ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADEMPS.LOADDATE
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADEMPS.LOADNUM
INNER JOIN  (   SELECT      LOADDATE, LOADNUM, COUNT(LOADROLE) AS TYPECODE
                FROM        LOADEMPS 
                GROUP BY    LOADDATE, LOADNUM
            ) AS LOADTYPE   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADTYPE.LOADDATE 
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADTYPE.LOADNUM

ORDER BY ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDLOAD, LOADROLE
```

Answer (score 0):

For prosperity, you can also load these onto global temporary tables.

The advantage of of using a global temp table over a `CTE` or traditional temp table is that the global table can be initialized in a stored procedure and then referenced in another stored procedure nested within the outer one.

It also lets you use super fast and loose `SELECT ... INTO` syntax without needing to define a table ahead of time.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Global_Temp 
FROM (
SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 1 AS LOADROLE, LOADDRIV AS EMPID, RATEDRIV AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE LOADDRIV>0
UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 2 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP1 AS EMPID, RATEHLP1 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP1>0
UNION SELECT LOADDATE, LOADNUM, 3 AS LOADROLE, LOADHLP2 AS EMPID, RATEHLP2 AS RATE FROM CERTODB.LOADS WHERE RATEHLP2>0
);

SELECT ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDACCT, ORDLOAD, TYPECODE AS LOADTYPE, EMPID, RATE

FROM        CERTODB.ORDERS AS ORDERS

                                      -- THE SUBQUERY BELOW IS THE FIRST DUPLICATION
INNER JOIN  (                       SELECT LOADDATE, LOADROLE, EMPID, RATE FROM #Global_Temp 
            ) AS LOADEMPS   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADEMPS.LOADDATE
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADEMPS.LOADNUM
INNER JOIN  (   SELECT      LOADDATE, LOADNUM, COUNT(LOADROLE) AS TYPECODE
                                      -- THE SUBQUERY BELOW IS THE SECOND DUPLICATION
                FROM        (       SELECT LOADDATE, LOADROLE, EMPID, RATE FROM #Global_Temp 
                            ) AS LOADEMPS
                GROUP BY    LOADDATE, LOADNUM
            ) AS LOADTYPE   ON  ORDERS.ORDDATE = LOADTYPE.LOADDATE 
                            AND ORDERS.ORDLOAD = LOADTYPE.LOADNUM
ORDER BY ORDDATE, ORDNUM, ORDLOAD, LOADROLE;

DROP TABLE #Global_Temp;
```

Comment: The only time to consider global temporary tables instead of CTE is if you have multiple statements that will need the same data.  A CTE as much less overhead.  In addition, if a CTE is materialized, by the system, it can be shared among jobs.  A global temp table can not be shared, it's only global to the job.